# How to find the index of the 2nd (or 3rd) largest value of a column in a df (Python)?

Tags: python, sorting, max, data-cleaning

I want to find the second largest value of each column but want to collect the position where this value can be found (in short: what is the equivalent of .idxmax when using .nlargest(2).values[-1] ?)

Here is my reasoning to obtain the 2nd and 3rd highest values:

```
test_2ndmax = pd.DataFrame({'Col{}'.format(i):np.random.randint(0,100,5) for i in range(5)})
display(test_2ndmax)

#retrieving 2nd higest value for each column
display(test_2ndmax.apply(lambda col: col.nlargest(2).values[-1],axis=0))

#retrieving to get 3rd higest value
display(test_2ndmax.apply(lambda col: col.nlargest(3).values[-1],axis=0))
```

The output is as such:

```
    Col0    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
0   9       15      24      45      85
1   26      50      91      34      60
2   3       88      84      17      53
3   8       58      73      56      11
4   82      65      93      3       46

Col0    82
Col1    65
Col2    91
Col3    45
Col4    60
dtype: int32

Col0    26
Col1    58
Col2    84
Col3    34
Col4    53
dtype: int32
```

However, I would like to get this, as I would using an equivalent of idxmax: (exemple for col.nlargest(2).values[-1]),

```
Col0 4
Col1 4
Col2 1
Col3 0
Col4 1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get index of second largest value use `.nlargest(2)` + `.idxmin()` (similar for third largest...):

```py
x = test_2ndmax.apply(lambda col: col.nlargest(2).idxmin(), axis=0)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
Col0    3
Col1    3
Col2    4
Col3    4
Col4    1
dtype: int64
```

---

DataFrame used:

```
   Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0    64    10     6    49    94
1     4    22    86    79    82
2    84    92    25     1    43
3    87    41    18    51    29
4    96    40    73    70    74
```